# Javascript false control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I want the script not to run unless I am less than 5 trainqueue_barracks

but I put 100 here and it doesn't work either. What's wrong?

```js
if ( document.document.getElementById("trainqueue_barracks") == null 
  || document.document.getElementById("trainqueue_barracks").rows.length < 5
   ) {
```

[image: 1]

Comment: what is the value returned by `document.document.getElementById("trainqueue_barracks").rows.length` ?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have tagged jquery, you can simply do it like this:

```
if(!$('#trainqeueu_barracks').length || $('#trainqeueu_barracks tr').length < 5)
{
   ...
}
```

Note that `!$('#trainqeueu_barracks').length` will be always true in your case, so the second part won't actually matter. I think what you really need is:

```
if($('#trainqeueu_barracks tr').length < 5)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231765/discussion-between-beast-who-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't need the first condition of your loop

```
document.document.getElementById("trainqeueu_barracks") == null
```

Also if you put 100 in their then it shouldn't work and your code is right. Unless you want it to run when rows.length is >= 5.

```
document.document.getElementById("trainqeueu_barracks").row.length >= 5
```

Is the opposite end of what you have.

Comment: I know I just tried here and unfortunately it doesn't work